# Linking to assets on a cdn with cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cdn

I am getting ready to deploy a cakephp app onto the web and i want to move all the assets (img, js, css) to a CDN to increase performance. Is there a way to globally change the location the HTML helper links to assets instead of having to change every link.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I came across this cool helper that accomplishes this task with relative ease. It's called **[Asset Host Helper](https://github.com/teknoid/cakephp-asset-host-helper)** and can be obtained from its **[GitHub repository](https://github.com/teknoid/cakephp-asset-host-helper)**.

What I liked best about it is that you don't need to worry about changing the location of the assets in your development copy (most likely on localhost) or in your production copy (on the CDN). The helper takes care of it automatically.

Check it out - this might just be the tool you're looking for.

Cheers,
m^e

Answer (score 1):

If the routes and filenames persist, maybe mod_rewrite might be less painful.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/css/
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ http://cd.yourdomain.com/css/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: wouldn't this cause two http requests?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, here's how I solved it:
[Adding a prefix to every URL in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794412/adding-a-prefix-to-every-url-in-cakephp/1878334#1878334)

The `AppHelper::url()` method is the place you should be interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but it involves changing the core, I know I know...I have already slapped myself for doing it ;-)

We had a project that was built and then needed a CDN so we just added a bit of code to the HTML and Javascript helpers to assist us.

In the /cake/libs/view/helpers/html.php file add this at line 360

```
if (Configure::read('Asset.CDN.enabled')) {
    $static_servers = Configure::read('Asset.CDN.static_servers');

    if(sizeof($static_servers) > 0) {
        shuffle($static_servers);
        $url = $static_servers[0].$url;
    }
}
```

and in /cake/libs/view/helpers/javascript.php ass this at line 288

```
if (Configure::read('Asset.CDN.enabled')) {
    $static_servers = Configure::read('Asset.CDN.static_servers');

    if(sizeof($static_servers) > 0) {
        shuffle($static_servers);
        $url = $static_servers[0].$url;
    }
}
```

Then in your app/config.core.php file just add the following configuration options

```
// Static File Serving on a CDN
Configure::write('Asset.CDN.enabled', false);
Configure::write('Asset.CDN.static_servers', array('http://static0.yoursite.com.au/', 'http://static1.yoursite.com.au/'));
```

Now when you refresh your page each file that is outputted through the html/javascript helper will automatically pick a random static server.

Note that unless you are using absolute paths (including domain names) in your css files you will need to make sure the images are also on the static server.

I know you shouldn't really play around in the core but sometimes it is really just easier.

Cheers,
Dean

Comment: You could/should inject the URL in `AppHelper::url()` (after getting the real URL from `parent::url()`), then you could stop slapping yourself. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question but in case any future people stumble across it in rails 3.1 you can now use

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "ATBTracking"
```

in `config/environments/production`

Comment: Except this post is about CakePHP, not Rails ;-)