# How can I append .html to all my URLs in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, url-rewriting

I am using cakephp in one of my projects and my client wants the site URLs to end with .html and not the usual friendly urls. I was wondering if its possible in cakephp to do so through any of its routing techniques. Please help.

Comment: Also see [Adding a prefix to every URL in CakePHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794412/adding-a-prefix-to-every-url-in-cakephp)

Comment: i suggest u explain to ur client why its important

Comment: It sounds like the client may need more education. I cannot think of any reason why a .html extension would be needed. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: well its an SEO thing. when the search engine crawler finds a page with an extension of .html it assumes that its a static page and gives it more ranking. i am not sure if this is followed these days by the modern crawlers but my client wants it so i have to give it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to solve this without using Routes. Kept the default route entry for pages:

```
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

and in the display action removed the .html extension and rendered the respective view:

```
preg_replace('/\.html$/','',$view);
$this->render(null,'default',$view);
```

While calling the pages added 'ext' to be .html

Answer (score 12):

That is well documented in the [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/952/File-extensions).

UPDATE: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#file-extensions

> To handle different file extensions with your routes, you need one
>   extra line in your routes config file:

```
Router::parseExtensions('html', 'rss');
```

> If you want to create a URL such as /page/title-of-page.html you would
>   create your route as illustrated below:

```
Router::connect(
    '/page/:title',
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'view'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('title')
    )
);
```

> Then to create links which map back to the routes simply use:

```
$this->Html->link(
    'Link title',
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'view', 
          'title' => 'super-article', 'ext' => 'html')
);
```

Comment: I think there must be a better approach which can add .html to all controller's action rather than providing ext=> 'html' to every controller manually. Also, if want to turn on/off .html extension it makes no sense to go to all controller and manually add/remove ext parameter. What do you say if someone wants to make Joomla like seo on/off?

Comment: @RNKushwaha: You can inject file extension to every link in AppHelper::url() if that is what you meant by your comment.

Answer (score 5):

One of the parameters you can send to Router::url() (which is called by other methods like HtmlHelper::link() and Controller::redirect()) is 'ext'. Try setting this to 'html'. E.g:

```
echo $this->Html->link('Products', array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'index', 'ext' => 'html'));
```

or

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'index', 'ext' => 'html'));
```

If it works, try figuring out a way you can override Router::url() to add it in by default.

Comment: In Cakephp 3 you can use the parameter '_ext' that is sent to Url Helper.  [see more - https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/url.html]

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](http://www.webdevelopment2.com/the-secret-of-cakephp-advanced-routing-even-better-urls/) you can do something like this

`Router::connect('/(.*).html', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));`

but as you are talking about extensions, that may have other consequences.

Comment: Hi Lucas Heneks, Thanks for the link. I tried it but it doesn't seem to work for me... It giving me the missing controller error.

Answer (score 2):

As [Routes Configuration - File extensions](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Configuration.html#file-extensions) documentation section says, you could use:

```
Router::parseExtensions('html', 'rss');
```

This will tell the router to remove any matching file extensions, and then parse what remains.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to associate the html extension to the PHP module in Apache as well.  I don't remember exactly the adjustment needed but it will be in /etc/httpd/httpd.conf file. (This file may be in a slightly different place depending on your server's OS.) Just look for the line that associates .php with the PHP module. I believe you may be able to define this in the .htaccess file as well but weather or not you can depends on what you are allowed to do in the httpd.conf file.

Comment: That won't be necessary since Apache will just route everything through Cake, extension and all, since none of the .html files actually exists. You only need to do what you describe if you have physical HTML files which you want processed by PHP, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite Simple,Open file app/config/routes.php and  just add

```
Router::parseExtensions('html', 'rss');
```

Above the line

```
 Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
```

Now you can access even your controller methods with .html extensions .

I hope it helps .