# Routes in not redirect to index.html page

Tags: routes, cakephp-1.3

I am coding on cakephp 1.3. I have a problem redirecting the page to index.html.

My index.html is inside webroot folder.
What I know cakephp will directly redirect to index.html.

When I using URL it is showing error..

```
Error: Controller could not be found.

Error: Create the class Controller below in file: app/controllers/controller.php

<?php
class Controller extends AppController {

    var $name = '';
}
?>
```

I have followed some link but it not seems to work.
I have checked on Google also.

[How can I append .html to all my URLs in cakephp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410611/how-can-i-append-html-to-all-my-urls-in-cakephp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't replace CakePHP's own index.php or CakePHP will stop working. Normally you can put files in webroot and it would work without problems, but the root file is a bit more trickier, since (AFAIK) you can't use Cake's routing only to display a non-CakePHP file.

Put your html file in a view in any controller and route the root directory there. For example, name the file index.ctp and put it in app/views/static_pages/index.ctp.

Router:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'static_pages', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Controller (static_pages_controller.php):

```
class StaticPagesController extends AppController {
    function index() {
        // no need to do anything except use no layout file
        $this->layout = false;
    } 
}
```

Model (static_page.php):

```
class StaticPage extends AppModel {
    // don't use a database for this model
    var $useTable = false;
}
```