# I want to redirect page in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I have URL :-

```
http://mydomain/test/index.html
```

I want when user will enter this in url :- `http://mydomain/test`

It will redirect to `http://mydomain/test/index.html`..

What i have tried I gave code in routes.

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'enrollments', 'action' => 'index'));
```

I want to redirect to index.html page how to give..

Comment: Where exactly is the index.html page? Did you put it in app/webroot/test/?

Comment: You can't access index.html in webroot. index.php takes precedence and you can't remove it, otherwise CakePHP stops working. Why do you need to have a static html file anyway, can't you add it as a static CakePHP action and redirect the root to that?

Comment: @Juhana is there any way to do this ..

Comment: I've written an answer to [the duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630018/routes-in-not-redirect-to-index-html-page). Please don't re-post questions.

Comment: Use the [PagesController](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/958/The-Pages-Controller) for this. There is no point in implementing custom controllers to serve static content when this is already a part of the CakePHP Core.

Comment: @BorislavSabev will you please give some demo code.. I am really want to implement it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Pages Controller](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/958/The-Pages-Controller) is generally used to serve static pages. Eg. If you make a view file *app/views/pages/about_us.ctp* you can access it using url *http://example.com/pages/about_us*.

If you have [baked your app](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1522/Code-Generation-with-Bake), the Pages controller should have been copyed to your `app/controllers/` folder and be able to modify it or you could just copy the `pages_controller.php` from core to your app. However if you don't need to modify it, i.e. in order to just display static content you do not need to copy the pages controller to `app/controllers/`.

**How to display a static page?**

Well if you make a view file `app/views/pages/index.ctp` you can access it using url `http://example.com/pages/index`. Then to modify the route you can:

```
Router::connect('/test', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', index));
```

However this will not provide `http://www.example.com/test/index.html` but: `http://www.example.com/test/index`.

Comment: +1 for help thanks. i want same result in this url ; http://www.example.com/test/ i mean when i will run this it will redirect to http://www.example.com/test/index.html..

Comment: You can use [Router Extensions](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/945/Routes-Configuration#File-extensions-952) but this would affect the whole app. My advice, just leave it as it is.